# ebpf: do ternary lookups exist?

Tags: linux-kernel, lookup, bpf, ebpf

Is there a `map` in `ebpf` that can do ternary lookup? I know there exist LPM map for longest prefix match, but I would like to have something like this:

```
val & 0xF0F01234 == 0x10101234
```

Comment: As @Qeole answered, there are no such maps at the moment. It is, however, possible to emulate this kind of lookups if you have a low enough number of masks. How many different masks do you expect to have?

Answer (score 2):

Not at this time. If you have a solid use case for this, you could suggest people to implement it (asking on iovisor-dev or netdev mailing lists maybe, or just asking about it to the maintainers). Or better yet, propose a patch set :-).